# Filtering a Seq of Tuple3 using one element of each Tuple

Tags: scala, tuples, seq

I have a `Seq` of `Tuple3` elements.
I want a resulting collection (probably a `Set`) made up with the **second** element of each tuple.

For example

```
(a, b, c), (d, e, f), (g, h, i) ==> (b, e, h)
```

Any idea? I searched a lot but all I'm finding has to do with filtering on the tuples, not within them, if that makes any sense.

I'm still quite new to Scala, learning is a long process :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yourSeqOfTuples.map(tuple => tuple._2).toSet`, which may be shortedned to `yourSeqOfTuples.map(_._2).toSet`

You may use {} rather than () if you prefer it so.
`_2` is the method which gets the second element of the tuple.

Comment: Both you and Ben James gave me the same answer at the same time, you get the tick for the extra explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

From your description of what you want, which is some function of type `Seq[(A, B, C)] => Set[B]`, you need to map, rather than filter. For example,

```
scala> Seq(('a', "foo", 1), ('b', "bar", 2)).map(_._2).toSet
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String] = Set(foo, bar)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't like the clumsy tuple accessors (_1, _2, etc.), a "partial function literal" where you can use pattern matching:

```
scala> Seq(('a', "foo", 1), ('b', "bar", 2)) map { case (_, x, _) => x } toSet
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String] = Set(foo, bar)
```

Comment: I don't find them clumsier than your partial function literal to be honest, but thanks anyway for this alternative method. Very interesting.

Comment: Yeah, in this case I would also go for the other approach. Using case and a tuple pattern becomes particularly awesome if you need access to all parts of a Tuple. Then giving sensible names to the parts is ways more understandable that using _x multiple times.

Comment: Yes agreed, this looks really powerful